# Discord bot how to assign role in python

Tags: python-3.x, discord, bots, roles, verification

I tried to find information online, but all assign role discord bot are reaction verification instead of specific human verification. I want to add the code which will assign the role `Student` with the ID of `1135057095327236226` after the email verification has passed.
**Code**

````
    global data_frame
    id = str(id.upper())
    data_frame = pd.read_csv('student_list_all.csv')
    result = data_frame[data_frame['學號'] == id]
    if choice == 1:
        return result['班級']
    elif choice == 2:
        return result['英文名']
    elif choice == 3:
        return result['中文名']
    elif choice == 4:
        return result['社團']`

`def handle_response(message) -> str:
    global stored_verification_code, student_id
    student_id = ""  # Initialize student_id

    p_message = message.lower()

    if p_message.startswith(('# XXX', '# YYY')) == True and len(p_message) == 7:
        student_id = p_message
        student_id_verification_code[0] == (student_id)
        verification_code = ''.join(str(random.randint(0, 9)) for _ in range(16))
        print(verification_code)
        student_id_verification_code[1] = (verification_code)
        stored_verification_code = verification_code
        email_verification_mappings[student_id] = (verification_code, time.time())
        content = MIMEMultipart()
        content["subject"] = "學生會 Discord 認證碼 / Student union Discord verification code"
        content["from"] = "# my gmail acc"
        content["to"] = f"# student's gmail acc"
        content.attach(MIMEText(f"Your verification code\n{verification_code}\n"))
        stored_verification_code = verification_code  # Update the stored code

        with smtplib.SMTP(host="smtp.gmail.com", port="587") as smtp:
            try:
                smtp.ehlo()
                smtp.starttls()
                smtp.login("# my gmail acc", "# my gmail acc key")
                smtp.send_message(content)
                return "The verification code has already been sent to your gmail, and it will only be available for 10 minutes, please check your gmail as soon as possible."
                print("Complete!")
                result = get_value_from_sheet(student_id)
                print(result)
                return result  # Return the result
            except Exception as e:
                print("Error message: ", e)
                return "Not being able to sent verification email. Please report the bug or issue to the administrator as soon as possible."

    if p_message[:8] == "!verify ":
        parts = p_message.split()
        if len(parts) == 3:
            student_id = parts[1]
            verification_code = parts[2]

            # Check if the email address has a recent verification code
            stored_code, timestamp = email_verification_mappings.get(student_id, (None, 0))
            current_time = time.time()

            if stored_code == verification_code and current_time - timestamp <= 600:  # 10 minutes = 600 seconds
                # Code is valid, do something (e.g., mark the email as verified)
                del email_verification_mappings[student_id]  # Remove the used verification code
                return "Verification successful! You are now verified. Your roles will be given by the bot automatically in a minute. If there is a problem, please contact the administrator."
                if message.author != client.user:
                    member = message.author
                    # role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, id="1135057095327236226")
                    role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name=f"{stu_info(student_id, 1)}")
                    member.add_roles(role)
                    message.channel.send('Done. "Student" role has been added.')

                    
                    # !!! And here is the problem, where I couldn't assign role, and always return error.

                    
                    message.author.edit(nick=f"{stu_info(student_id, 2)}")
                    if role is not None:
                        print(role.name)
                        message.author.add_roles(role, reason=None, atomic=True)
                        return f"You've been added to {find_stu_class(student_id)} role."
                        print("Role added.")
                    else:
                        print("Role 'Student' not found.")
                        return "Role 'Student' not found. Please contact the administrator."

                    return "role \"Student\" has been added successfully."
            else:
                return "Invalid verification code or expired. Please try again."```

My verification process work perfectly fine, but it just can't assign role, and I hope someone could help me fix this bug. Thanks a lot. 
```@async def on_message(message):
     if message.content == "give me admin"
           role = discord.utils.get(server.roles, name="Admin")
           await client.add_roles(message.author.id, role)```
I've tried the templet of the others, but everytime I use the code `await client.add_roles(message.author.id, role)`, it suddently bugged.
````